# How can I utilize my Event class methods in bankSim class?

Tags: java, static-methods

when i compile my bankSim class, I get the error: non-static method setWhichQ(int) cannot be referenced from a static context.  What can I do to reference my Event class methods in the bankSim class?  Just below this is processArrival which is where the error occurs.  After that is my entire event class.

```
public void processArrival(Arrival arrEvent, Arrival[] inputData, int inputDataIndex,
                               SortedList<Event> eventList, QueueDSVector<Arrival> teller1, QueueDSVector<Arrival> teller2) {

        boolean atFront1 = teller1.isEmpty();  // am I the only one here?
        boolean atFront2 = teller2.isEmpty();


        if (atFront1) {    // if no other customers, then immediately get served
            Departure newDep = new Departure(arrEvent.getArrTime(), arrEvent);
            // because this customer's next Event will be a departure
            eventList.insert(newDep); // put the departure into eventList
        } // end if

        else if (atFront2) {    // if no other customers, then immediately get served
            Departure newDep = new Departure(arrEvent.getArrTime(), arrEvent);
            // because this customer's next Event will be a departure
            eventList.insert(newDep); // put the departure into eventList
        } // end if

        else if ( teller1.size()< teller2.size() ) {  //queue of teller 1 is less than teller 2
               teller1.enqueue(arrEvent);  // put new customer into bank line to wait

               Event.setWhichQ(1);
        }

        else if (teller2.size() < teller1.size()) { 
               teller2.enqueue(arrEvent); 
               Event.setWhichQ(2);
           }




public abstract class Event implements Comparable<Event> {



  protected int whichQ;


    public Event() {
        whichQ = 0;
    }

    public int compareTo (Event other) {
        int thisTime = this.getTime();
        int otherTime = other.getTime();

        return (thisTime - otherTime);
    }

   public int getWhichQ() {
      return whichQ;
    }
//    
   public void setWhichQ(int q) {
        if (q >= 2)
            whichQ = 2;
        else if (q<=1)       // < 0 = 0 
            whichQ = 1; 
        else
            whichQ = q;
    }

    public abstract int getTime(); 
    public abstract String toString(); 

} // end Event class
```

Comment: What programming language is this in? The only tag you've included is static-methods.

Comment: @furkle Java, sorry bout that just added it

Comment: Added an explanation below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to be that you're calling Event.setWhich(), which is referencing the Event type, not an Event object. In order to use a non-static method, you have to first instantiate the object:

```
Event test = new Event();
```

then call the method on that instantiated object:

```
test.setWhichQ(1);
```

Likewise, if you wanted to use the setWhichQ() method as you've indicated above, you'd have to change Event to a static class, and make whichQ a static field. In this case, Event.setWhichQ() could be called with a reference to the class itself, and could likewise modify whichQ.